# How to access context.identity from a Python AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My lambda function is receiving a context.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info(context.function_name)
    logger.info(context.identity)
    logger.info(context.cognito_identity_id)
    logger.info(context.identity.cognito_identity_id)
    return 'hello world'
```

The log receives the function_name, and logs the memory address for `context.identity`. But `context.cognito_identity_id` and `context.identity.cognito_identity_pool_id` are reported as `None`.

How do I get `cognito_identity_id` populated?

From Xcode debugger in the class built by AWS API Gateway I can see that the private variable `_configuration._credentialsProvider._identityId is set correctly. But this value isn't being passed thru to my AWS Lambda function.

I can't find how to get is passed thru. I've read this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html) where I'd expect it to be covered.

Further:
From the Lambda function I logged out `dir(context.identity)` giving `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'cognito_identity_id', 'cognito_identity_pool_id']`

This shows that `cognito_identity_id` and `cognito_identity_id` are actually present.

I think AWS Gateway -> AWS Lambda doesn't set-up Identity for free - I'm missing some configuration - a mapping template perhaps.

Comment: Are you invoking the Lambda function through the AWS Mobile SDK?

Comment: I'm using API Gateway to call the Lambda function. But it should make no difference how it's called. I just need the object documenting

Comment: The documentation is on the page you linked: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html identity "Information about the Amazon Cognito identity provider when invoked through the AWS Mobile SDK. It can be null."

Comment: I read that page. In my case the value is not null. So how do I get the fields from my context.identity object?

Comment: @mark b are you writing Python lambda functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've made progress.

Drop the GET method - it doesn't support the passing of Cognito identities thru to Lambda.

Use POST instead.
For the POST's Integration Request select "Invoke with caller credentials" and create a Mapping template. The template needs to be "application/json" with the Template contents `{ "identity": "$input.params('identity')" }`

With these additions, when the lambda function is called its `context.identity' parameter will be populated with the values of the caller's cognity identifier pool and id.

From Python in your Lambda function be sure to access with `context.identity` and not `context[identity]`

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment...

You will need to look at the API Gateway documentation. I know that the Cognito identity ID is `None` if you

(a) invoke the lambda using the CLI with an `(access key id,secret key)` as credentials,

(b) invoke the lambda using boto using `(access key id,secret key)` credentials,

(c) invoke the lambda from the AWS console.

I invoke my Lambdas using Cognito credentials, and I get a non-`None` identity id in my context object. To set up Cognito credentials you need to set up an identity pool with a role which is authorized to invoke the function (simple setup: create an unauthorized role and give it the *lambda:invokeFunction* permission for your function).

I can provide Python or JavaScript code to do this, though it wouldn't answer your question because you specifically asked about invocation from the API Gateway. But if you want it let me know.

Comment: Btw I looked at the API Gateway documentation and it looks like it doesn't know how to talk to Cognito i.e. the Cognito identity can't be put into the HTTP headers or anything like that. Quite possibly the API Gateway is meant to be used for public & anonymous interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Chatterjee. Does context.identity have a value and cognito_identity_id is None?

Comment: is this Python syntax correct `context.identity.cognito_identity_pool_id` ?

Comment: That syntax is correct. You can find it on page 54 of the Lambda developer's guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dg.pdf). I find that these developer guides are better than any of the online documentation / blogs / tutorials etc.

Comment: And to answer your first question, `context.identity` is indeed non-null with two null members (the identity id and the identity pool id) in the case you're asking about

Comment: The API Gateway does support Cognito. "API Gateway provides you with tools to authorize access to your APIs and control service operation access. You can use AWS administration and security tools, such as AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) and Amazon Cognito, to authorize access to your APIs" from http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/ -- it's just not straightforward ;)

Comment: Oh good! I wonder how they do it... I will probably look at the API Gateway service in a few weeks, if I find the answer I will come back here and update it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

So from the event

```py
UserPoolId = event['identity']['claims']['iss'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```